# How can I change the height of an image in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, resize

I am trying to adjust the height of an image by stretching it.
This is what I've got so far:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped{
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"water.png"];
[water1 setImage:img];  
}
-(IBAction)button2Tapped
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)img 
          scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,2,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;}
```

and this is in my view controller.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *water1;
-(IBAction)buttonTapped;
-(IBAction)button2Tapped;
```

I am not sure what I need to change to make this correct, or if I should start again with a new way.
I want it so that when I push a button, an image appears, then it resizes it when I push another button.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the size of the UIImageView property, in order to get the size you want.

Set the contentMode of the UIImageView to wathever fits your need, and it will automatically resize to the given size (either scaling to fit or stretching).

Comment: I want it to be able to change size to get bigger or smaller when I push a button, to represent a valu, according to its size, if this is possible?

Comment: So just change the with & height of the view.frame.size :)